# Start ngrok HTTP tunnel, but only forward to either HTTP or HTTPS, not both

Tags: ngrok

When I start an HTTP tunnel, ngrok automatically starts forwarding on both HTTP and HTTPS.
Is there a way to only start one of them?

Answer (score 9):

Currently, to force the scheme (http instead of https) it is:

```
ngrok --scheme http http 8080
```

^ Binds to the 8080 port of the localhost

Answer (score 2):

**Tunneling to HTTP or HTTPS only**

By default, when ngrok runs an HTTP tunnel, it opens endpoints for both
HTTP and HTTPS traffic. If you wish to only forward HTTP or HTTPS
traffic, but not both, you can toggle this behavior with the **--scheme**
flag.

Example: Only listen on an HTTP tunnel endpoint

```
ngrok http --scheme=http site.dev:80
```

Example: Only listen on an HTTPS tunnel endpoint

```
ngrok http --scheme=https site.dev:80
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the `bind-tls` option in your ngrok config.
`--bind-tls "true"`

Docs here: https://ngrok.com/docs#http-bind-tls

Comment: `--bind-tls "true"`